# Having a dynamic rest view duplicates the user-list url

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, dynamic-rest

(I have a custom user model)

I do not understand why this is happening. These are my expected urls:

```
python manage.py show_urls
/api/v1/        rest_framework.routers.APIRootView      api-root
/api/v1/\.<format>/     rest_framework.routers.APIRootView      api-root
/api/v1/users/  users.views.UserCreateViewSet   user-list
/api/v1/users/<pk>/     users.views.UserViewSet user-detail
/api/v1/users/<pk>\.<format>/   users.views.UserViewSet user-detail
/api/v1/users\.<format>/        users.views.UserCreateViewSet   user-list
```

As soon as I include in my `urls.py` a view based on `DynamicModelViewSet`:

```
from dynamic_rest.viewsets import DynamicModelViewSet


class AggregateViewSet(DynamicModelViewSet):
    pass
```

My `user-list` urls are duplicated:

```
» python manage.py show_urls
/api/v1/        rest_framework.routers.APIRootView      api-root
/api/v1/\.<format>/     rest_framework.routers.APIRootView      api-root
/api/v1/users/  users.views.UserCreateViewSet   user-list
/api/v1/users/  users.views.UserViewSet user-list
/api/v1/users/<pk>/     users.views.UserViewSet user-detail
/api/v1/users/<pk>\.<format>/   users.views.UserViewSet user-detail
/api/v1/users\.<format>/        users.views.UserCreateViewSet   user-list
/api/v1/users\.<format>/        users.views.UserViewSet user-list
```

This is my (simplified) `urls.py`:

```
from django.urls include
from rest_framework.routers import DefaultRouter

# from consumption.views import AggregateViewSet

router = DefaultRouter()
router.register(r'users', UserViewSet)
router.register(r'users', UserCreateViewSet)

urlpatterns = [
    path('api/v1/', include(router.urls)),
]
```

Activating that `from consumption.views import AggregateViewSet` statement makes the problem appear. It does not even need to be registered to the router: just importing the view is breaking the urls.

Why is `dynamic-rest` mangling the urls *just by being imported*?